# Bootstrap Navbar text alignment

Tags: html, css

[This is how I want to align text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DS4q.png):

[image]

[And this is my navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ3sg.png):

[image]

I've been trying for exactly 2 days to make this style, somehow I couldn't do it like on Max Back's site

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container bg-light mt-5">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <img src="assets/icon.jpg" width="48" height="48" class="rounded-circle" alt="">
      <span>Emre İlhan</span>
      <img src="assets/icons8-verified-account-20.png" alt="">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"><span class="tex-black-50">01</span> Active</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="tex-black-50">02</span> Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="tex-black-50">03</span> Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback, this is my first time using stackoverflow, I will correct my mistakes as soon as I use it

Comment: You're very welcome, thank you for being receptive to that feedback, and for editing - and improving - your question.

Comment: span or img which is used for name and verified icon to be block level element to resolve this img{ display: block; }

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for navbar text-right

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-right" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: direkt kopyala yapıştır cevabı olmuş :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<style>
    .img-container{
        background-color: black;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid rgb(76, 76, 76);
    }
    .img{
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
    .main{
        display: flex;
    }
    .text{
        margin-left: 5px;
        padding: 3px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="main" >
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="33720.jpg" class="img" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <div>Emre Ihan <i class=" fa fa-check"></i></div>
            <div style="color: gray;"><i class=" fa fa-check"></i>offical</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help to put this into the boostrap navbar
i will try to integrate